# insert and update in vb.net with access index out of range

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i have application  i want it to do 
1- insert the first statement .
2-get the (maxid) of the invoice 
3-insert the detail of the invoice with the Id .
it give me this error
index out of range .

```
Private Sub insert()
    Dim invoiceday As Date = Today
    Dim userid As Integer
    Dim clientid As Integer
    Dim note As String
    If clients.Visible = True Then
        userid = 1
        clientid = 2
        note = "cash"
    Else
        userid = 2
        clientid = 6
        note = "credit"
    End If
    Dim query1 As String = " insert into invoices([purchasedate],clientid,[Note],userID,total,disq) Values  ( '" & CDate(invoiceday) & "','" & clientid & "','" & note & "','" & userid & "','" & totalprice.Text & "','" & txtdis.Text & "')"
    samselect2(query1)
    Dim maxinvoice As Integer
    maxinvoice = invoiceid()

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dvsale.Rows
        Dim query As String = " insert into invoicede(invoiceid,barcode,doaname,Qty,Price,qtyprice)  Values ('" & maxinvoice + 1 & "','" & row.Cells("barcode").Value & "','" & row.Cells("doaname").Value & "','" & row.Cells("qty").Value & "','" & row.Cells("price").Value & "','" & row.Cells("tqty").Value & "')"

        samselect2(query)
    Next

End Sub
```

this the class of the samselect2

```
 Public Sub samselect2(ByVal sql As String)
        Try
            con.Open()
            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = sql
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        End Try
        con.Close()
        da.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

and the invoiceid max number

```
Private Function invoiceid()
        checkConnection()
        Dim strQ As String = "SELECT max(invoiceID)as MaxIDbatch  from invoices "
        Dim cmdQ As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strQ, con)
        Dim result = cmdQ.ExecuteScalar()
        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim x As Integer = 0
            Return x
        Else
            Return result
        End If


    End Function
```

Comment: Mind showing what "samselect2" does? Also what is "invoiceID()"? This tell's me that it's possible that maxinvoice isn't anything that your getting from "invoiceid()"

Comment: i have add the samselect2 and the invoiceid() .

Comment: Don't use `SELECT MAX(id) ...`, use `SELECT @@IDENTITY` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't fully understand your question, I notice a couple things: 1) It appears that InvoiceID is not an auto-incrementing identity field, and it probably should be.  (Check out "Is Identity".)  If it were, you could insert and specify all fields except that one, and the number would increment automatically.  2) In your for...each, you are not increasing maxinvoice at all with each iteration through the loop.  Although you're using maxinvoice+1, it will still be the same number each time.

Still, all of that should be unnecessary if you make InvoiceID an identity field.

Comment: invoiceID is auto-incrementing after the first table filled with the invoice number i want it to fill the second table with the product detail  so i want to get the invoice id to add it the second table maxinvoice+1 is mistake from my side it is maxinvoice only